# Add to routed a dynamically created view, without file

Tags: sapui5

I have to implement a totally dynamic SAPUI5 application. This application is completely assembled through the data that comes from a service. With this data I have to create, dynamically, the views, the controllers and the routing.

I've almost managed to create views and routing dynamically, but I have a serious problem. When I create a view from a controller I can not add it to the routing. Unfortunately the "addRoute" method needs as a parameter the "view" attribute where the path must be put to the file that defines the view. But in my case said file does not exist, I'm creating the view directly in a controller.

I pass the example so that you can see it:

```
var sMenu = "newView"; // <-- hardcode

if(!this.getRouter().getRoute(sMenu)) {
    var xmlView = '<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"            '
        + '              controllerName="com.iberdrolaEficiencia_v2.controller.Container">    '
        + '          <Page showHeader="false">                   '
        + '             <Panel headerText="Hello World">                             '
        + '                <Button text="lo que sea" press="doSomething"></Button>'
        + '             </Panel>                                                     '
        + '          </Page>                                                     '
        + '       </mvc:View> ';

    // instantiate the View
    var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({ id : sMenu, viewContent : xmlView });

    // introduce la vista como parte de las rutas
    var oRoutingViews = new sap.ui.core.routing.Views();
    oRoutingViews.setView("base." + sMenu, oView);

    // add new route
    this.getRouter().addRoute(
        {
            pattern : sMenu,
            name : sMenu,
            view : "base." + sMenu, // fail because there is no file with that name
            targetControl : "navMain",
            targetAggregation : "pages"
        }, this.getRouter().getRoute("Home"));

    this.getRouter().initialize();
}

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).navTo(sMenu, []);
```

In short the question would be, **how do I add to the routing a view created in the controller?**

Regards.

Comment: Is this maybe an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? You can have a real, but empty view and populate that dynamically, too.

Comment: I have a low level of English and maybe I have not explained clearly. But in summary the specific question would be: How can I add a view created in the controller to Routing? Thank you